# .HLSL file for OpenGL Shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I'm trying to make a simple OpenGL application using [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/) tutorial. It says I can give shaders whatever file extention I want. However, in VS2013, when I click "add new item", go to Visual C++ tab and add a Pixel Shader or Vertex Shader, it doesn't compile right and I get errors. Why is this happening? Why can't I use the .hlsl files for my shaders while a regular .txt simply compiles?

Errors I get:

- error x3000
- error x1504

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not the file extension but the compiler options associated with the file. When creating one of the `hlsl` files in visual studio, their default `Item Type` (can be seen in the property panel) is `HLSL Compiler`. This means that the compiler chain tries to compile this files with the hlsl compiler which is not going to work out when the file contains `glsl` code.

You can either switch the item type manually to `Text` (or something else that has no compilation associated), or you use an other extension. I personally would NEVER name a glsl shader file *.hlsl anyhow because every other person in the project will assume it to contain hlsl code.

Answer (score 0):

Hlsl is the extension for DirectX shaders. When you add an hlsl file in Visual, it recognises it and tries to compile it as a DirectX shader, wich is of course different from OpenGL shaders. I recommend using glsl files.